# PHPUNIT Test Coverage disable html report

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony5.4

can I disable generate html files?

[image]

```
bin/phpunit --colors=never --log-junit /tmp/tests_report.xml --coverage-text
```

but html files still generate

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

Need to remove from phpunit.xml.dist

```
    <report>
        <html outputDirectory="./var/report" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </report>
```